# Is it possible to mount entire Vue 2 application in React using module federation?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-module-federation

Hello I'm trying to mount Vue 2 app - generated by Vue CLI 5 - which has nothing inside only 2 routes created by CLI tool - my goal is to mount it in my host app which is React 17 app.

I'm wondering if it is possible ? I see that `remoteEntry` file is beeing fetched correctly by the host React app:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

When I'm trying to mount it I'm stuck on following error:

```
error Error: Module "." does not exist in container.
while loading "." from webpack/container/reference/@zx-mfe/vueRemote
```

Here is my `vue.config` setup for module-federation

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false
    },
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'vueRemote',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        exposes: {
          './sharedApp': './src/expose.ts'
        }
      })
    ]
  }
})
```

And the expose file for Vue

```
//app content
// export default new Vue({
//   router,
//   render: h => h(App)
// }).$mount('#app')

import app from './main'

export default app
```

And in React here is the module federation setup

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "host",
        remotes: {
          "@zx-mfe/vueRemote": "vueRemote@http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js",
        },
      }),
```

And the Loader component where I would like to mount entire Vue app

```
import React from 'react';
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';

//@ts-ignore
const VueApp = React.lazy(() => import("@zx-mfe/vueRemote")
.then((res) => {
  console.log('res', res)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('error', error)
}));

export const VueAppLoader = () => {
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback="loading">
      <ErrorBoundary fallback={<h2>Failed to load Vue Application</h2>}>
        <VueApp />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </React.Suspense>
  )
}
```

I have seen that with Vue 3 it will be way easier, but I'm wondering if it will be possible to the same with Vue 2 to support older projects. Thank you for any advice